# Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "modelInfo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

This is the error I receive when fetch data

```
<template>
  <main>
    {{ modelInfo }}
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import searchByNameQ from '~/apollo/queries/models/searchByNameq'

export default {
  async asyncData({ $strapi }) {

    // Fetch model data
    const modelInfo = await $strapi.graphql({
      query: searchByNameQ.loc.source.body,
      variables: { name: ['Transit Custom'] }
    })

    return {
      modelInfo
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

On refresh and nuxt-link this works. But it errors with hot module update. The output of modelInfo is:

```
{
    "models": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Transit Custom",
        "size": "mellem"
    }]
}
```

EDIT: Found the error. This code is correct, but the error is caused by a by a config in `nuxt.config`

I have been having this setting, because it fixed a Google Analytics issue. When this config is removed, there is no error.

```
  features: { transitions: false },
```

Comment: That code is located in which folder/file?

Comment: It is a page located in:
`pages/_brands/_models/index.vue`

Comment: Hot module replacement seems to be a little buggy sometimes. I need to refresh the page a lot, to be sure it is not an actual error.

Comment: Although, if would moslty set v-if="modelInfo" on main or so. modelInfo has no value in the beginning ... actually you should get an error for that, but a different one. Try that in case

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this setting in nuxt.config, because it fixed a Google Analytics issue. When this config is removed, there is no error.

```
  features: { transitions: false }
```